# How do I access the "config" menu in FCEUX?

Tags: emulation, nes

I am using FCEUX 2.2.2 on Kubuntu 14.10. This [help page](http://www.fceux.com/web/help/Config.html) alleges the existence of a "Config menu", with various useful options in it. I can't find this Config menu anywhere though. This is what the FCEUX window looks like for me (with some ROM loaded). Right-clicking on the menu bar or inside the game does nothing. How do I get to this menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The menu you're looking for isn't in the Linux build, unfortunately -- it's Windows only. The GUIs are entirely different between the two, and a lot of features are missing from the Linux one. Your best bet is to try using WINE or a virtual machine if possible.

Here is a screenshot showing the Windows equivalent of that menu, with the options shown in the help file:

[image: FCEUX config menu on Windows]